# Insert code that contains "" or () into texfield

Tags: java, text, insert, jtextfield, symbols

How can I set textfield with sql code like this:

```
sqlcodefield.setText("("Select IP from Test where (Ipdate > 01.01.2010)");")
```

well it sure doesnt work cause there are multiple "" and (). Hope you understand.I dont need to execute any query just insert code in textfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quote characters `"` are used to indicate the beginning and ending of a string. They need to be escaped within a `String` to indicate that they are a special character. To set the text for the `JTextField`, you can use

```
sqlcodefield.setText("(\"Select IP from Test where (Ipdate > 01.01.2010)\");");
```